# Calling user defined functions in Package Manager Console in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, powershell, nuget-package

I created a default ClassLibrary project in visual studio. Then I added an basic class that has one method in it.

[image]

Then I opened Package Manager console in visual studio. And I run standard Regex replace method on it and it works. Then I try to run my own replace method but it didnt work. Is there any way to run user defined methods on Package manager console or is it only allowed by core libraries on windows ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell needs to [load the type first](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx) before it can call it.

> Add-Type -Path c:\test\ClassLibrary1.TestClass.cs
>
> [ClassLibrary1.TestClass]::Replace("testx","x","y")

You could also put the add-type call into your [NuGet_profile.ps1](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console), and load your DLL if there will be multiple classes you need to call.